# Can we "invert" Diophantine equations such as $x^3+y^3+z^3=k$ in to halting probabilities for some universal Turing machine?

Tags: diophantine-equations, decidability

Following Poonen [[1]](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Epoonen/papers/h10_notices.pdf), Davis[[2]](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-035-02/S0002-9939-1972-0304347-1/), Chaitin [[3]](https://doc.lagout.org/Others/Information%20Theory/Information%20Theory/ALGORITHMIC%20INFORMATION%20THEORY%20-%20G.J.%20Chaitin.pdf), and Ord and Kieu [[4]](http://amirrorclear.net/files/on-the-existence-of-a-new-family-of-diophantine-equations-for-omega.pdf):

> Is it possible that there is a polynomial $P$ of degree $d\le 4$, along with a prefix-free universal Turing machine $T$, such that the $k^{th}$ bit of the halting probability, $\Omega_T$, is $0$ if and only if
>
> $$P(x,y,z)=k$$
>
> has an infinite (or even) number of solutions?

A lot of attention has been given to questions about the decidability of

$$x^3+y^3+z^3=k$$

However, after Heath-Brown [[5]](http://eprints.maths.ox.ac.uk/156/1/wa.pdf) [[5a](https://web.archive.org/web/20180721183108/http://eprints.maths.ox.ac.uk/156/1/wa.pdf)] it might be reasonable to say that if $k$ doesn't have an obstruction mod 9 then it can be represented as the sum of three cubes in an infinite number of ways.

Nonetheless I always liked Chaitin's results (and Ord and Kieu's follow-up), but Chaitin concedes that his explicit construction of an exponential Diophantine equation with a parameter encoding an $\Omega$ is, at 17,000 variables, in his words "a little large."

After learning that problems as simple as the sum of three cubes can have such a dynamic and complex behavior, I'm wondering if Chaitin's construction can be "reversed" in some sense, by starting from a much simpler Diophantine equation to find a universal Turing machine?  Have we learned a lot in the last twenty years or so about if and how complexity begets universality?